# Function forward reference works exceptionally

Tags: javascript

Three similar snippets include function forward reference, but behave differently. The first one seems to me odd. Why?

```
function foo() { bar(); }
function bar() { return "bar"; }
alert(foo());
```

```
-> undefined
```

```
function foo() { bar(); }
function bar() { alert("bar"); }
foo();
```

```
-> bar
```

```
function foo() { return bar; }
bar = "bar";
alert(foo());
```

```
-> bar
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first example `foo` does not have a `return` statement so it returns `undefined` no matter what the return value of `bar()` is.

To correct it to give the same result as others, add a `return` statement.

```
function foo() { return bar(); }
function bar() { return "bar"; }
alert(foo());
```

Comment: Unlike perl or ruby, function always return the value of the last evaluation. I was stuck transitively.